# Using $(this) within .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a series of elements laid out in HTML

I am trying to get the value of the `href` for each div with the class `wsite-com-category-product-wrap` and then use this to insert a new button with the same href.

My current code is inserting all the links (for items with the class `.wsite-com-category-product-wrap`) into themselves meaning that each element has about 10 links in now instead of just the one.

The code I have written to do this:

```js
$(".wsite-com-category-product-wrap").each(function() {

  var link = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
  $("<a href=" + link + " class='custom-category-button'>Test</a>").insertAfter(".wsite-com-product-price");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wsite-com-category-product-wrap">
  <a href="#" class="link">Link content</a>
  <div>more divs</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the `.wsite-com-product-price` element? Presumably you need to use DOM traversal to relate it to the `this` element within the iteration.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made with enough html and script to show the issue

Comment: @dwinnbrown , can you give us code for class wsite-com-product-price? where is the html code for that. Can you please provide that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a jquery object with [.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/), not just a string selector.

So, change this:

```
$("<a href=" + link + " class='custom-category-button'>Test</a>")
    .insertAfter(".wsite-com-product-price");
```

to:

```
$("<a href=" + link + " class='custom-category-button'>Test</a>")
    .insertAfter($(".wsite-com-product-price", this));
```

Comment: This is the right answer! See my updated answer below...using this on the `insertAfter` was the error. Stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I found that with the `insertAfter` I needed to add in something ensuring it was only being added to `$(this)`.

I used a new variable `insertHere` to make it simpler:

```
$(".wsite-com-category-product-wrap").each(function() {

    var link = $( this ).find("a").attr("href");

    var insertHere = $(this).find(".wsite-com-product-price");
    $( "<a href=" + link +" class='custom-category-button'>Test</a>" ).insertAfter( insertHere );
});
```